# What's the difference between C++ Concept and Java Interface?

Tags: java, c++, interface

I've been doing some reading on Concepts that are going to be introduced in C++14/17. From what I understood, we define and use a concept like this:

```
// Define the concept (from wikipedia)
auto concept less_comparable<typename T> {
    bool operator<(T);
}

// A class which implements the requirements of less_comparable,
// with T=`const string &`
class mystring
{
    bool operator < (const mystring & str) {
        // ...
    }
};

// Now, a class that requires less_comparable
template <less_comparable T>
class my_sorted_vector
{
    // ...
};

// And use my_sorted_vector
my_sorted_vector<int> v1;                  // should be fine
my_sorted_vector<mystring> v2;             // same
my_sorted_vector<struct sockaddr> v3;      // must give error?
```

My question is, isn't this conceptually pretty much the same as a Java Interface? If not, how are they different?

Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that concepts and inheritance have *absolutely nothing to do with each other*, *at all*? And also that Java interfaces are weakly typed and concepts are very strongly typed?

Comment: @FredOverflow You can achieve a concept-like effect by not using concepts. If a template parameter is not compatible with its usage in the code, the code will currently fail to compile (albeit with confusing error messages).

Comment: @DeadMG Yes, I know. I deleted my comment. It was too rant-y. Sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java interfaces define types. For example, you can have a variable of type `Comparable<String>`. C++ concepts do *not* define types. You cannot have a variable of type `less_comparable<string>`.

Concepts *classify* types just like types classify values. Concepts are one step above types. In other programming languages, concepts have different names like "meta-types" or "type classes".

Comment: +1 for "Concepts classify types just like types classify values".

Comment: If anything, concepts are most similar to `extends` constraints on generics in Java, or at least, the intentions are similar.

Comment: Does that means that is not possible to write a function like: `public bool someFunc(less_comparable<int> a, less_comparable<int> b){return a < b;}` Don't take too seriously the usefulness of the method.

Comment: @JavierMr `template<less_comparable T> bool someFunc(T a, T b) { return a < b; }`

Comment: @FredOverflow But what you suggest is that both parameters have the same type T, what I was trying to define is a function that accepts to objects of potentially different types as long as they are comparable as ints. Maybe something as `template<less_comparable T, less_comparable R> bool someFunc(T a, R b) { return a < b; }`

Answer (score 0):

Java interfaces require an inheritance relation. Concepts act more like [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), any object that provides the operators/members required by a concept is compatible with it.

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer but my understanding is that interfaces and inheritance are distinct in Java (keywords `implements` vs `extends`). For example, a Java class can implement any number of interfaces but Java allows only single inheritance.

Comment: @Praxeolitic Java only allows single inheritance of implementation ( extends ) to avoid the "diamond problem" of conflicting base classes. Interfaces still use inheritance, they are just limited to implicitly abstract member methods ( recently relaxed by default methods ) and may not contain member fields ( diamond problem: how many copies of this state exist per object, which one is valid?). Outside of this one vs. many limitation the language handles both the same.